# Are there standards to follow when using the ClaimValue in AspNetUserClaims?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity, claims-based-identity, asp.net-authorization

VS2013, MVC5, VB

Many posts including here on SO state that claims can increase authorization granularity without incurring a large proliferation of roles.  I hope I said that right.

Am I correct in thinking this is only accomplished by using the ClaimValue property?

Even if that's not correct, if the ClaimValue property is used, then some kind of scheme must be employed in assigning the ClaimValue.  Are there standard or typical ways to use ClaimValue?  Or do we just devise what we need for a given situation?

**Addition to post:**  Regards the comment above about roles: I ask this question because many in the community use claims as roles but it seems that is not the initial/primary purpose for the development of claims in MVC5.

So I should add to my question also asking "Is the use of claims for roles OK?", or should I just be creating a permissions structure, leaving the MVC claims facilities for what seems to be its intended purpose, that of storing identity claims, as opposed to being used with regard to authorization.

Comment: I've removed the VB tag since this is cross-language and added some applicable identity tags.

Answer (score 1):

An authority will "dictate" what each claim type's standard is (or should be) for the claim value but you don't have to follow them unless you are trying to play nice with something of theirs. [Here's an example](http://docs.oasis-open.org/imi/identity/v1.0/os/identity-1.0-spec-os.html#_Toc229451870) of one such authority

You can invent your own claim types (and claim value standards) or make up your own standard for one of the existing claim types. They are left ambiguous to be very flexible.

Really, the whole point of making a standard is interoperability. If you don't expect to ever need to do that then it's not a big issue when you don't follow an authority on claims.

You can see a nice list of some commons claims [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.identitymodel.claims.claimtypes_members.aspx). Note that one of these you can see is `http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2008/06/identity/claims/role` so trivially you can see that roles are ok.